# how can I create a component where I can add as many levels of subpoints I can recursively in a react component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript, recursive-datastructures, recursive-type

Earlier my component had only one level of subpoint so,

it would look like

main point 1

- subpoint 1
- subpoint 2

main point 2

- subpoint 1

For this my code looked like this

```
    interface PointCardProps {
    pointData: {
      mainPoint: string
      subPoint: string[]
    }[] 
  }

export const singleNest = (props:PointCardProps) => {
    return(
        <ol>
        {props.pointData.map((value) => {
          return (
            <>
              <li>
                <div>
                  {value.mainPoint}
                  <div>
                    <ul>
                      {value.subPoint.map((point) => {
                        return <li>{point}</li>
                      })}
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </li>
            </>
          )
        })}
      </ol>
    )
}
```

How can I change the component in such a way that it can have any amount of levels

eg:
main point 1

- sub point 1
- sub point 2

  - sub point 2.1

    - sub point 2.2

      - sub point 2.2.1

need to start with changing interface, please help

Comment: `pointData` should be recursive. Should `subPoint` contain another `pointData` ? Example: `type Tree<T> = {
    node: T,
    tree: Tree<T>
}`

Comment: @captain-yossarian I haven't worked much on typescript so I don't what that means can you show a small dummy data to show how `type Tree<T> = {     node: T,     tree: Tree<T> }` looks like ?

Comment: Sure ,  https://tsplay.dev/N52lBm

Comment: @captain-yossarian yes this was something I was thinking about. not sure how to do the points part Recursively, I am rushing against time so don't really have the luxury to sit and think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have recursive react component with recursive props:

```js
type Point = {
  point: string;
  subpoints: Point[];
};

const points = {
  point: "0",
  subpoints: [
    {
      point: "1",
      subpoints: [
        {
          point: "2",
          subpoints: []
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

const RecursiveList = (props: Point) => {
  const { point, subpoints } = props;
  console.log({ subpoints });

  return (
    <>
      <div>{point}</div>
      <ul>
        {subpoints.map((elem, index) => (
          <RecursiveList key={index} {...elem} />
        ))}
      </ul>
    </>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return <RecursiveList {...points} />;
}
```